# Text alignment in org-mode numbered lists?

Tags: org-mode

**Q:** Is there a way to prepend zeros to `org-mode` numbered lists?

Text alignment in numbered lists starts to look unpleasant when numbers get into the double digits:

```
* A numbered list

  1. Item 1
  2. Item 2
  3. Item 3
  4. Item 4
  5. Item 5
  6. Item 6
  7. Item 7
  8. Item 8
  9. Item 9
  10. Item 10   # ah, my eyes!
```

The `org-mode` manual on [plain lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Plain-lists.html) states that:

> Items belonging to the same list must have the same indentation on the first line. In particular, if an ordered list reaches number ‘10.’, then the **2–digit numbers must be written left-aligned with the other numbers in the list.** An item ends before the next line that is less or equally indented than its bullet/number.

So it looks like `org-mode` needs the digits to left-align.  As such, I'm wondering if it's possible to prepend zeros onto the single-digit items so that the text aligns nicely:

```
* A zero-padded numbered list

  01. Item 1
  02. Item 2
  03. Item 3
  04. Item 4
  05. Item 5
  06. Item 6
  07. Item 7
  08. Item 8
  09. Item 9
  10. Item 10   # much better!
```

Out of curiosity, I tried hand-entering the zeros in a list and hitting `C-c C-c`, which simply strips them out again.

So: *is there any way to convince `org-mode` to prepend zeros in numbered lists?*

(Note: question inspired by [this S.O. thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432613/emacs-clean-up-numbered-lists-with-more-than-9-lines).)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The following diff on `org-list.el` does the trick!

```
diff --git a/lisp/org-list.el b/lisp/org-list.el
index b1d47c9..509e79f 100644
--- a/lisp/org-list.el
+++ b/lisp/org-list.el
@@ -1641,7 +1641,8 @@ as returned by `org-list-prevs-alist'."
      ;; Num bullet: increment it.
      ((string-match "[0-9]+" bullet)
       (replace-match
-       (number-to-string (1+ (string-to-number (match-string 0 bullet))))
+       (format (format "%%0%dd" (length (match-string 0 bullet)))
+          (1+ (string-to-number (match-string 0 bullet))))
        nil nil bullet))
      ;; Alpha bullet: increment it.
      ((string-match "[A-Za-z]" bullet)
@@ -1715,7 +1716,7 @@ This function modifies STRUCT."
          (replace-match "a" nil nil bullet))
         ;; First bullet is num: use "1".
         ((string-match "\\([0-9]+\\|[A-Za-z]\\)" bullet)
-         (replace-match "1" nil nil bullet))
+         (replace-match (format (format "%%0%dd" (1+ (log (length struct) 10))) 1) nil nil bullet))
         ;; Not an ordered list: keep bullet.
         (t bullet)))))))))
     (mapc fix-bul (mapcar 'car struct))))
```

The first chunk patches function `org-list-inc-bullet-maybe` to keep
the padding used on the first item. The second chunk patches function
`org-list-struct-fix-bul` to calculate the padding based on the number
of elements in the list.

Comment: Nice! It would be great if you could submit that (preferably with an option to toggle it) to the org-mode developers.